# returned object to pointer jna with qt

Tags: java, c++, qt, jna

I am working on a JNA project:

- Some files are written in JAVA.
- Other ones are written in C++ (QT).
- A CPP file is linking JAVA and C++.

The JAVA project use the version 3.0.9 of JNA: 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jna/jna/3.0.9

I am using QT 5.2 and JAVA 1.7 on Windows 8.
I copy qt dll from qt folder to my JAVA project in order that the application can work.
I do not know how, in a JAVA method, I get an returned object from a method that belongs to a dll. I saw the documentation about Pointer, but I do not find the appropriate kind for getting an object from a developed method in a dll.

my qt project file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-05-17T21:25:07
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       -= gui

TARGET = composite
TEMPLATE = lib

SOURCES += classes/my_component_class.cpp\
        classes/my_composite_class.cpp\
        wrapper.cpp

HEADERS += classes/my_component_class.h\
        classes/my_composite_class.h
```

classes/my_component_class.h:

```
#ifndef MY_COMPONENT_CLASS_H
#define MY_COMPONENT_CLASS_H

class MyComponentClass {

private:

    int myFirstField;
    int mySecondField;

public:
    MyComponentClass();
    MyComponentClass(int,int);
    void setMyFirstField(const int&);
    void setMySecondField(const int&);
    const int& getMyFirstField() const;
    const int& getMySecondField() const;
};

#endif
```

classes/my_component_class.cpp:

```
#include "classes/my_component_class.h"
MyComponentClass::MyComponentClass(){
    myFirstField = 0;
    mySecondField = 0;
}

MyComponentClass::MyComponentClass(int _myFirstField,int _mySecondField){
    setMyFirstField(_myFirstField);
    setMySecondField(_mySecondField);
}

void MyComponentClass::setMyFirstField(const int& _myFirstField) {
    myFirstField = _myFirstField;
}

void MyComponentClass::setMySecondField(const int& _mySecondField) {
    mySecondField = _mySecondField;
}

const int& MyComponentClass::getMyFirstField() const{
    return myFirstField;
}

const int& MyComponentClass::getMySecondField() const{
    return mySecondField;
}
```

classes/my_composite_class.h:

```
#ifndef MY_COMPOSITE_CLASS_H
#define MY_COMPOSITE_CLASS_H

#include <QList>
#include "classes/my_component_class.h"

class MyCompositeClass {

private:

    QList<MyComponentClass> list;

public:

    MyCompositeClass();
    void setList(const QList<MyComponentClass>&);
    const QList<MyComponentClass>& getList() const;
    QList<MyComponentClass>& refList();
};

#endif
```

classes/my_composite_class.cpp:

```
#include "classes/my_composite_class.h"
MyCompositeClass::MyCompositeClass() {
    list << MyComponentClass(1,2);//Some objects are added to the list
    list << MyComponentClass(3,4);
}
void MyCompositeClass::setList(const QList<MyComponentClass>& _list) {
    list = _list;
}

const QList<MyComponentClass>& MyCompositeClass::getList() const{
    return list;
}

QList<MyComponentClass>& MyCompositeClass::refList() {
    return list;
}
```

wrapper.cpp:

```
#include "classes/my_composite_class.h"

extern "C"{

    static MyCompositeClass* composite = NULL;

    void create(){
        if(composite == NULL) {//Create once
            composite = new MyCompositeClass();
        }
    }

    void* list() {
        create();//Avoid segmentation fault
        //Does it exist an other way to get pointer from the returned list?
        return &(composite->refList());
    }


    void destroy(){
        if(composite != NULL){
            //Delete the instance only if there is a created instance
            delete composite;
            composite = NULL;
        }
    }

}
```

I am working on Windows 8, so the output dll is composite.dll

IComposite.java:

```
package mainPackage;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
public interface IComposite extends Library{

    //Load dll once
    public IComposite INSTANCE = (IComposite) Native.loadLibrary("composite", IComposite.class);

    //usable methods in the JAVA code
    public void create();
    public void destroy();
    public Pointer list();
}
```

CompositeSample.java:

```
package mainPackage;
public class CompositeSample{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path_ = CompositeSample.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        if (path_.endsWith(".jar")) {
            //In order to treat executable jars, it is recommanded to change
            //the property of java.library.path
            System.setProperty("java.library.path", path_.substring(1)+"!/");
        }
        IComposite integerMath = IComposite.INSTANCE;
        integerMath.create();
        // What do I have to do with the returned pointer from the method "list" of the interface "IComposite"
        // in order to get the list from the returned pointer?
        integerMath.destroy();// free allocated memory
    }

}
```

Thanks for the people who will be able to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a professional in JNA, so this is just a hint.
I don't think that it's possible to magically get the value contained in a pointer of non primitive type. In my opinion you should create a mapping type in Java for your `MyComponentClass`. Unfortunately I don't know how.

If I were you I would do it the easy way; create a struct that will contain my data and use this struct as a return value instead of returning the whole class object.

check this example to see how to map a struct and how to send/retrieve an array of structs using JNA 
http://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/example06.html

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, Java doesn't know anything about the QList type so you see it only as an opaque pointer in your Java code. To fix this, you could either expose a plain C API only, or provide a Java Qt wrapper.

Take a look at [Qt Jambi](http://qt-jambi.org/). It's a Java binding for Qt that will let you use Qt types in Java. Specifically, the [Jambi generator](http://qt-jambi.org/doc/generator) will automatically generate a Java wrapper for your C++ code and automatically convert between Qt collections and Java collections.